# Fit a curve to a probability distribution

Tags: r, probability, distributions

I have a set of data that I computed from options data that approximates the probability distribution for a stock price over a range of strikes.

I'd like to fit a probability distribution curve to this set of points and ensure the area sums to 1 to get a clean and proper approximation of the PDF for this stock.

```
c(0, 0, 0.000208182692011079, 0.000218784525845072, 0.000230059271947993, 
0.000242058672718367, 0.000254838379387282, 0.000268458247556603, 
0.000282982655233351, 0.000298480841289281, 0.000315892450183093, 
0.00033177571333295, 0.000351594508953066, 0.000371790376764847, 
0.000393392550588617, 0.000416507813019018, 0.000441250819664667, 
0.000467744620936399, 0.000496121207211382, 0.000526522070894631, 
0.000559098786584436, 0.000594013604115059, 0.00063144004951123, 
0.000671563532642906, 0.000714581949133379, 0.000760706274163098, 
0.000810161136824336, 0.000863185364037901, 0.000920032482212203, 
0.000980971162878999, 0.00104628559342781, 0.00111627575798244, 
0.00119125760338323, 0.00127156306985695, 0.00135753995879761, 
0.00144955160976205, 0.0015479763562244, 0.00165320672580597, 
0.00176564835146426, 0.00188571855576092, 0.00201384457065479, 
0.00215046135443622, 0.00229600896783627, 0.00245092947131941, 
0.0026156633105474, 0.00279064515861609, 0.00297629918788382, 
0.00317303375592016, 0.00338123549397851, 0.00360126279815904, 
0.00383343874001874, 0.00407804342460469, 0.00433530583981816, 
0.00460539526768577, 0.00488841233745145, 0.00518437983339691, 
0.00549323338480143, 0.00581481219429517, 0.00614884997878448, 
0.00649496632360488, 0.00685265866204061, 0.0072212951174443, 
0.00760010844534187, 0.00798819132944373, 0.00838449327401418, 
0.00878781933535065, 0.00920235579065385, 0.00960406151573376, 
0.0100258994251216, 0.0104425591685407, 0.0108582112192999, 0.0112708942255356, 
0.0116785592846201, 0.0120790881407616, 0.0124703136112951, 0.0128500419750558, 
0.0132160769852766, 0.0135662451089561, 0.013898421542141, 0.0142105565036963, 
0.0145007012879337, 0.0147670335342418, 0.0150078811785113, 0.0152217445685119, 
0.0154073162583277, 0.015563498049048, 0.015689414907186, 0.0157844254656245, 
0.0158481289035581, 0.0158803680844464, 0.0158812289337082, 0.015851036124199, 
0.0157903452329375, 0.0156999316068183, 0.0155807762596536, 0.015434049165761, 
0.0152610903834758, 0.0150348273984722, 0.0148655128903583, 0.014599313139285, 
0.0143373338009998, 0.0140576030560211, 0.0137620206040843, 0.0134525018607133, 
0.0131309578281978, 0.0127992764540384, 0.0124593056752163, 0.0121128383057532, 
0.0117615988639484, 0.0114072323825452, 0.011051295207065, 0.0106952477361143, 
0.0103404490268709, 0.00998815316370013, 0.00963950725091575, 
0.00929555089430587, 0.00895721700096429, 0.00862533374377682, 
0.00830062751680837, 0.00798372672395231, 0.00767516624042386, 
0.00737539240188923, 0.00708476837900641, 0.00680357982021808, 
0.0065320406403079, 0.00627029886537835, 0.00601844244326069, 
0.00577650494885332, 0.00554447112615978, 0.00532228221544077, 
0.0051098410335592, 0.0049070167738962, 0.00471364951112101, 
0.00452955439887319, 0.00435452555282539, 0.00418833962042336, 
0.00403075904710442, 0.00388153503561023, 0.00374041022631383, 
0.00360712109311651, 0.00348140008857629, 0.00336297753880994, 
0.00325158331341941, 0.0031469482859769, 0.0030488055984534, 
0.0029568917484379, 0.00287094751658219, 0.00279071874212274, 
0.00271595697349799, 0.00264641999095257, 0.00258187222986091, 
0.00252208510611137, 0.00246683725597659, 0.00230712920813222)
```

I tried to fit polynomials as follows

```
model <- lm(density ~ poly(strike,4), xdist)
```

but get behavior at the tails that looks non 'normal', i.e. the curve turns 'up' as follows (the different colors are for different polynomials I tried):

[image: options pd]

I want to use these PD's to get a CDF for the stock price that is well formed.

Comment: Use `dput` to provide data. And voting for migration to StackOverflow

Comment: Finding a polynomial fit is not the normal way to estimate parameters for a normal distribution.

Comment: I am voting to leave open as I suspect (not sure) that there is room for discussion about the right thing to do statistically. What about `plot(density(y))`?

Comment: @ChristophHanck  The current form of the question makes it eligible for SO. But yes, the statistical method can be discussed here.

Comment: You might consider fitting curves to the *log* of the density. For a normal, the log-density is quadratic. Indeed one form of nonparametric density estimation uses cubic-splines in the log-density. However (depending on how the data are obtained)  you may be better using GLMs to fit the model (e.g. with counts, you might look at a Poisson GLM with log link). There is also software that can fit log-spline density estimates.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note is that, if I got your Q right, you will end up charting the pdf/cdf of the stock under the [risk neutral probability measure](http://people.stern.nyu.edu/jcarpen0/courses/b403333/13rnprob.pdf).

Second point: it is not clear whether you want to approximate your data with a gaussian or you'd like to approximate your data with something else (any parametric form, again polyfit. You could eventually even go freestyle and run a non parametric density estimation.